# What is the term for this?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I keep coming across "quotes" on the internet that say things like "psychology says, if a person blah blah"
I'm wondering what the term would be when someone 'mislabels' a field of study (psychology in this case) as a person, as if a field of knowledge is someone talking, I don't know how else to put this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'mislabelling'; it's a recognised shorthand for 'people who are experts in psychology'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the name of this literary device? 'Suddenly, the theater became silent.'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275315/whats-the-name-of-this-literary-device)

Comment: It's arguably not personification ('a field of study' already having undeniable human connections) but metonymy (using the field to represent typical/paradigmatic representatives). 'Whitehall has commented "No parties!" ' is a typically cited type of example. // For the reason Kate mentions, I've added scare quotes around 'mislabelling'. 'Mistreats' wouldn't work!  //  Does this answer your question? What's the name of this literary device? 'Suddenly, the theater became silent.'

Comment: I'm slipping, KillingTime. Good spot.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering what the term would be when someone mislabels a field of study (psychology in this case) as a person,

It isn't "mislabelling" at all. It is synecdoche (/sᵻˈnɛkdəki/).

OED **synecdoche**

> A figure of speech in which a more inclusive term is used for a less
> inclusive one or vice versa, as a whole for a part or a part for a
> whole.

"psychology says, if a person blah blah" *= people who study psychology say, ...*

Compare

"**The White House** announced its policy on orphaned kittens" = **A spokesman for the president** announced the president's policy on orphaned kittens"

See [Wikipedia - synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche)

Comment: Rather than *people who study psychology* I would imagine "psychology says" stands for *psychologists* and/or *psychiatrists* . In my opinion it's a metonymy.   It doesn't seem that much of a stretch, whereas "Buckingham Palace" in the news will often be short for "King Charles III's chief of staff/personnel/press secretary or private secretary  etc.